# Increase heap memory for 'gradle test'

Tags: gradle, jvm, build.gradle

I have a problem running 'gradle test' against my Spring Boot application as I see signs of GC called too many times and my tests fail likely due to delays caused by agressive GC work.

How I can tell gradle to use more heap memory allowed for JVM during test phase, or in general?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You can use the `maxHeapSize` configuration of the `Test` task.

Example in Gradle/Groovy:

```
test {
  minHeapSize = "128m" // initial heap size
  maxHeapSize = "512m" // maximum heap size
  jvmArgs '-XX:MaxPermSize=256m' // mem argument for the test JVM
}
```

Or the same in Kotlin:

```kotlin
withType<Test> {
  minHeapSize = "512m"
  maxHeapSize = "1024m"
  jvmArgs = listOf("-XX:MaxPermSize=512m")
}
```

Check out [the official docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html) for additional info.

Comment: Note that in Java 8+, `MaxPermSize` is no longer a thing: use `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m` instead